# Sort an array with respect to the Date in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsdateformatter, sorting

I have a tableview with values loaded from a web service. Which contains date value, here is how it looks like :

```
"Title":"Title1", 
"StartDate":"9\/15\/2011 12:00:00 AM",
"EndDate":"10\/15\/2011 12:00:00 AM".
```

I have done formatting using NSDateFormatter, I got the output as:

```
theDate: |09/22/2011| 
theTime: |14:09:30 PM|
```

Now I need to sort the Title in the tableview with respect to the corresponding dates of each title. How can I implement that? Please share your ideas...

And I need to implement this function on a button action, that is the sorting function should be performed on a button action.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor* nameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
NSMutableArray *temp = [yourArray mutableCopy];
[temp sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSorter]];
yourArray = temp;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

The same goes with titles as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.And I only need to print the titles in the table, but it should be sorted with respect to the corresponding dates of each title. So, can do it in the same way?

Comment: Yes you can proceed the same way.

Comment: having some problem, I got it sorted but looks likes this, "10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "10/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "11/16/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM",
    "9/15/2011 12:00:00 AM"  the format is "MM/dd/yyyy", I want to sort this based on day, then month, then year then time. How can I implement that?

Comment: from the array get time time out and put the date string in NSDateFormatter class and set it as MM/dd/yyyy format.